# SQL with Lookup Field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use a SQL statement to populate a ListBox in an Access Form.  The first ListBox shows printers we have available, and when you click a printer it is supposed to populate a second listbox with supplies and thier respective reorder numbers.

The "Printers" field is a lookup field based on another table.

When I run a SQL statement without any parameters or as long as I don't say `WHERE Printers = ...` it works just fine.  As soon as I try and filter my supplies by the printer selected then it just shows up blank like nothing matches the criteria.

Can anyone please help explain why the lookup field is giving me so much trouble?  Thanks in advance.

My table layout and form layout looks like this:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the ID was actually linking the tables, so when I ran `Where Printer = 1` it gave me the desired output.  So I undid the relationship, changed the lookup properties in design wizard to make the Printer data type 'Text' instead of 'Number', and made the column count 1.

So I guess this was my fault for not taking the time to map out every detail of the the process.